# Python subprocess or os.system not working with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, subprocess, os.system

I've been trying to get this darn programming run since last night and cannot seem to get anything to work. I want to first trim the video and then resize the video. I'm reading which video and what to give the final name from a text file, over 780 lines long, quite a few videos.

Thus far with every idea under the sun I have tried, subprocess and os.system, I can't get anything more than error statements or right now all I get is no file creation of any kind. How the heck do I get this to work correctly?

```
import ffmpeg
import subprocess
import os

os.chdir('/home/Downloads/SRs/')
a = open('SRt.txt', 'r')
b = a.readlines()
a.close()
for c in range(0, len(b)-1):
    words = list(b[c].split(" "))
    d = len(words)
    e = words[d-1]
    f = b[c].replace(e, 'FR' + str(c) + '.mp4')
    words[d-1] = 'FR' + str(c) + '.mp4'
    print(f)
    subprocess.call(f, shell=True)
    subprocess.call([
        'ffmpeg',
        '-i',
        "'FR' + str(c) + '.mp4'",
        '-vf scale=320:240',
        words[d-1],
        ])
```

Here are some examples of what the original file would look like:

```
 ffmpeg -i SR.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:01:22 -c:v copy -a copy CPH.mp4
 ffmpeg -i SR.mp4 -ss 00:01:24 -to 00:02:58 -c:v copy -a copy CG.mp4
 ffmpeg -i SR.mp4 -ss 00:02:59 -to 00:05:41 -c:v copy -a copy CSGP.mp4
```

Nothing fancy just separating video in its own individual segments and then resaving it before resizing it.

I tried:

```
z=subprocess.call(f, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(z)
```

But all I get is '1'.

When I changed it to:

```
z=subprocess.call(f, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(z)
```

All I get is '1'.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Please post a couple of lines of SRt.txt, and for each line, what do you expect the command line to be.

Comment: Just Standard debuging add stdout and sterr to subproccess and look what error is produced and resolve this

Comment: For the line ` ffmpeg -i SR.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:01:22 -c:v copy -a copy CPH.mp4`, what does your command line looks like?

Comment: The same other than I've replaced the CPH.mp4 with FR0.mp4. I don't want to have to screw around with overwriting a file so I keep the name the first time and change it and then when I go to resize the video I change the name back to what I wanted it to be in the first place. The line being sent to subprocess looks the same.

Comment: What about `-vf scale=320:240`? I don't see that in the SRt.txt file, but I see it in the code.

Comment: After the trimming then the resizing is supposed to happen. The trimming isn't occurring. The new FR0.mp4 should be created or the next subprocess call won't have the file to find.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how I understand your problem, here is what I came up with. My system does not have ffmpeg installed, nor do I have any video to test out, so I comment out the `subprocess.run()` line. All do is to transform the lines from the text file `SRt.txt` into commands which you can invoke.

```py
with open("SRt.txt") as stream:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(stream):
        # line_number=0 for line 1,
        # line_number=1 for line 2, ...

        command = line.split()

        # Last file name is tokens[-1]
        command[-1] = f"SR{line_number}.mp4"

        # Insert -vf scale=320:240
        command[-2:-1] = ["-vf", "scale=320:240"]

        print(line, end="")
        print(command)
        print()
        # subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
```

Content of my sample SRt.txt

```
ffmpeg -i SR.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:01:22 -c:v copy -a copy CPH.mp4
ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 -ss 00:01:24 -to 00:02:58 -c:v copy -a copy CG.mp4
ffmpeg -i bar.mp4 -ss 00:02:59 -to 00:05:41 -c:v copy -a copy CSGP.mp4
```

Output:

```
ffmpeg -i SR.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:01:22 -c:v copy -a copy CPH.mp4
['ffmpeg', '-i', 'SR.mp4', '-ss', '00:00:00', '-to', '00:01:22', '-c:v', 'copy', '-a', '-vf', 'scale=320:240', 'SR0.mp4']

ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 -ss 00:01:24 -to 00:02:58 -c:v copy -a copy CG.mp4
['ffmpeg', '-i', 'foo.mp4', '-ss', '00:01:24', '-to', '00:02:58', '-c:v', 'copy', '-a', '-vf', 'scale=320:240', 'SR1.mp4']

ffmpeg -i bar.mp4 -ss 00:02:59 -to 00:05:41 -c:v copy -a copy CSGP.mp4
['ffmpeg', '-i', 'bar.mp4', '-ss', '00:02:59', '-to', '00:05:41', '-c:v', 'copy', '-a', '-vf', 'scale=320:240', 'SR2.mp4']
```

Note: If you don't want the `-vf scale=320:240`, part, comment it out

Comment: Even when I take the comment out of the subprocess.run line and let it run, it doesn't process the video. It only comes up with the dialog, like you show on the screen. How do I get it to process the video correctly, like it should. When I type the line in the command line it works fine, but through Python it doesn't. Not with os.system or subprocess.

Comment: I don't know ffmpeg, I only know Python. Sorry.